# Understanding dimensions, coordinates and ordering of processes in a 2D MPI grid

Tags: c, mpi

I have 3 questions, all related to MPI (in C).  I think the first 2 have the same answer, but I'm not positive.

---

#### Question 1

**When using `MPI_Dims_create` to create a 2D grid, which dimension of the returned dimensions is X and which is Y?**

For example:

```
int numProcs = -1, myProcID = -1;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myProcID);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);

int size[2];
size[0] = size[1] = 0;
MPI_Dims_create(numProcs, 2, size);
int numProcs_y = -1, numProcs_x = 1;
```

Should it be:

```
numProcs_y = size[0];
numProcs_x = size[1];
```

Or this:

```
numProcs_x = size[0];
numProcs_y = size[1];
```

I tried running this with numbers of processes that seemed like they would give me the answer (e.g. 6).  With 6 processes, `MPI_Dims_create` should either create a grid with 3 rows and 2 columns or 2 rows and 3 columns (unless I've misunderstood the documentation). For process 3 (of 6), I found that `size[0] = 1` and `size[1] = 0` (I believe this corresponds to x = 0, y = 1). This seems to indicate to me that `MPI_Dims_create` is creating a grid with 3 rows and 2 columns (because it was 2 rows and 3 columns, process 2 (of 6) should have x = 2, y = 0).  Any confirmation someone could provide on this would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### Question 2

**When using `MPI_Cart_coords` on a 2D Cartesian grid, which of the returned dimensions is X and which is Y?**

For example:

```
int periodic[2];
periodic[0] = periodic[1] = 0; // no wrap around
MPI_Comm cart_comm;
int coords[2];

// using size from question 1
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, size, periodic, 1, &cart_comm);
MPI_Cart_coords(cart_comm, myProcID, 2, coords);
```

Similar to question 1, my question is, should it be like this

```
myProcID_y = coords[0];
myProcID_x = coords[1];
```

or like this

```
myProcID_x = coords[0];
myProcID_y = coords[1];
```

I've been searching through the documentation and previous questions on here, but I can't seem to find a direct answer to this question.

The documentation seems to indicate that the first of the two approaches is the correct one, but it doesn't definitively state it.

---

#### Question 3

The underlying question behind the first 2 questions is that I'm trying to split the 2D grid into rows and columns. However, when I use `MPI_Comm_rank` to check the row and column IDs of each process after doing so, I'm getting the processes ordered in an order that doesn't match with what I think the answers to the above questions are.

Based on above, I expect the processes to be ordered like this:

```
P0 P1
P2 P3
P4 P5
```

However, using this code (which comes after the above code in my program, so all the above code is accessible from it: I'm trying to separate out my code to make it easier to isolate my questions):

```
MPI_Comm row_comm, col_comm;
int row_id = -1, col_id = -1;
// ** NOTE: My use of myProcID_y and myProcID_x here are based 
// on my understanding of the previous 2 questions ... if my 
// understanding to one/both of those is wrong, then obviously the assignments 
// here are wrong too.
// create row and column communicators based on my location in grid
MPI_Comm_split(cart_comm, myProcID_y, myProcID_x, &row_comm);
MPI_Comm_split(cart_comm, myProcID_x, myProcID_y, &col_comm);

// get row and column ID for each process
MPI_Comm_rank(row_comm, &row_id);
MPI_Comm_rank(col_comm, &col_id);
printf("Process: %d\trowID: %d\tcolID: %d\n", myProcID, row_id, col_id);
```

I'm seeing the following printed:

```
Process: 0 rowID: 0        colID: 0
Process: 1 rowID: 1        colID: 0
Process: 2 rowID: 0        colID: 1
Process: 3 rowID: 1        colID: 1
Process: 4 rowID: 0        colID: 2
Process: 5 rowID: 1        colID: 2
```

which seems to correspond to the following order of processes:

```
P0 P2 P4
P1 P3 P5
```

which is the opposite matrix dimensions (2 rows, 3 columns) from what I was expecting from `MPI_Dims_create`.

**Assuming my understanding to the first 2 questions is correct (i.e. that Y is the first dimension returned by those functions), why are the processes (seemingly) being ordered in a different order at this step?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1 and Q2. There are no such things as dimension X and dimension Y in MPI - these are labels that you give to the abstract dimensions used in the standard. MPI works with numbered dimensions and follows the C row-major numbering of the ranks, i.e. in a `2x3` Cartesian topology `(0,0)` maps to rank `0`, `(0,1)` maps to rank `1`, `(0,2)` maps to rank `2`, `(1,0)` maps to rank `3`, and so on.

Note that dimension `0` corresponds to the *rightmost* element in the coordinate tuple. This is in *reverse* to the numbering of elements in C arrays and often a source of confusion. To create a `2x3` Cartesian topology the `size` array would have to be initialised as:

```
int size[2] = { 3, 2 };
```

It is up to you to map the abstract numbered dimensions to your problem. You may chose dimension `0` to be X, or you may chose dimension `1` - it doesn't matter.

As for `MPI_DIMS_CREATE`, the standard says:

> The dimensions are set to be as close to each other as possible, using an appropriate divisibility algorithm.
>
> For `dims[i]` set by the call, `dims[i]` will be ordered in non-increasing order.

This operation simply returns an array of elements `dims[i]` that have the following properties (unless the size of one or more dimensions is fixed by setting a non-zero value(s) in `dims[]` before calling `MPI_DIMS_CREATE`):

- `dims[0] >= dims[1] >= dims[2] >= ...`
- `dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2] == nprocs`, where `nprocs` is the number of processes, specified to `MPI_DIMS_CREATE`.

This means that as `MPI_DIMS_CREATE` decomposes the set of `nprocs` into an multidimensional grid, it would assign the biggest multiplier to the size of dimension `0`, the next one to the size of dimension `1`, and so on. As `6` factors like `2*3`, then `MPI_DIMS_CREATE` would return `{ 3, 2 }`. If you call `MPI_CART_CREATE` directly with the result from `MPI_DIMS_CREATE`, it would create a `2x3` topology with coordinates and ranks:

```
(0,0)=0 (0,1)=1 (0,2)=2
(1,0)=3 (1,1)=4 (1,2)=5
```

Q3. MPI provides a special routine to partition Cartesian topologies - `MPI_CART_SUB`. It takes an array of logical flags (integers in C), named `remain_dims` in the standard. Each non-zero `remain_dims[i]` means that that dimension `i` should be retained in the resulting partitioning while separate subcommunicators would be created for any possible combination of the non-retained dimensions. For example, given the `2x3` topology:

- `remain_dims[] = { 1, 0 }` would retain dimension `0` and result in 2 non-overlapping 1-d communicators with 3 processes each;
- `remain_dims[] = { 0, 1 }` would retain dimension `1` result in 3 non-overlapping 1-d communicators with 2 processes each;
- `remain_dims[] = { 0, 0 }` would not retain any of the two dimensions and will result in 6 non-overlapping zero-dimensional communicators with a single process in each.

Which partitioning you would call row-wise and which one you would call a column-wise partitioning is up to you and your labelling of the Cartesian dimensions.

---

One thing to note is that one often runs MPI codes on systems that consist of networked SMP or NUMA multicore nodes. In this case a suitable 2D grid would be `nodes x cores`. If the number of cores is known, then one can easily fix it in the call to `MPI_DIMS_CREATE`:

```
int size[2] = { ncores, 0 };

MPI_Dims_create(numProcs, 2, size);
```

This is a more convenient than dividing `numProcs` by `ncores` and checking for divisibility as `MPI_DIMS_CREATE` would signal an error if `ncores` does not divide `numProcs`. Then a partitioning that keeps dimension `0`, i.e. one with

```
int remain_dims[2] = { 1, 0 };
```

would create subcommunicators that contain processes on the same node, while

```
int remain_dims[2] = { 0, 1 };
```

would create subcommunicators that contain no two processes from the same node.

---

Note that in your code you have specified a value of `1 (true)` to the `reorder` parameter in `MPI_CART_CREATE`. This might lead to processes having different ranks in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and in the Cartesian communicator. Hence there is no guarantee that the following lines of code do what you expect them to:

```
MPI_Cart_coords(cart_comm, myProcID, 2, coords);
                           ^^^^^^^^
...
printf("Process: %d\trowID: %d\tcolID: %d\n", myProcID, row_id, col_id);
                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

`myProcID` was obtained from `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and might actually differ from the new rank in `cart_comm`, hence it should not be used to obtain the process coordinates and to perform the splits.

Comment: (not sure why this didn't post above)

Good to know about the X and Y dimensions.  One question: your 2x3 grid of process IDs assumes you assigned X to the 0th dimension, right (row major ordering seems to be 3 rows x 2 cols, assuming you assign the # of rows to the 0th dimension)?

I changed the reorder parameter to be false to prevent the condition you mentioned at the end, but I do get the same ordering of processes, namely the one with P0, P2, and P4 in row 0.  Are you saying that MPI_Comm_split() shouldn't be used on a Cartesian grid, and that MPI_Cart_sub() should be used instead?

Comment: You can probably ignore the first question.  I forgot what you said about the 0th dimension mapping to the rightmost element in the tuple.

I still am curious about the MPI_Cart_sub() question though.

Comment: @MattSinclair, no, I am not saying that you cannot or should not use `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` to perform partitioning on Cartesian grids. I am just saying that `MPI_CART_SUB` is more convenient and versatile, especially with higher dimensional grids. With colour/key-based splitting you would have to compute the colour and this gets more and more cumbersome with each added dimension. Besides `MPI_CART_SUB` creates Cartesian subgrids, while `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` creates simple communicators without an associated topology.